# Where is the value of SKStoreProductParameterProviderToken obtained from?

Tags: storekit, ios8.3

When setting product dictionary keys for SKStoreProductViewController the [Apple API Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKITunesProductViewController_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Product_Dictionary_Keys) mentions a new for iOS 8.3 token called SKStoreProductParameterProviderToken that can help with affiliate promotions.  There is no further description on where to find the value of this token, and the suggestion in the above link to review the *Viewing App Analytics* link had no mention of this new token at all.

Does anyone know where you find this?  I don't see it my iTunes Connect or the Developer Portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally burned an incident and just asked Apple directly to clarify.

For others who may hit this, the API documentation at the time of this post is missing some important details on this new SKStoreProductParameterProviderToken.

This token value is supplied by you, the developer, to assist in tracking your iTunes Connect App Analytics campaign.  It is an NSString instance which is 40 bytes in length and only available in iOS 8.3 and above.  No more, no less.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the accepted answer is not completely correct.
It is this way:

- `SKStoreProductParameterCampaignToken` is a name for your campaign you can invent and can be any String (max 40 bytes in length).
- `SKStoreProductParameterProviderToken` is the developer's Provider ID, who wants to see the campaign in the iTunesConnect App Analytics. You can look up the Provider ID [here](https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/#/campaigngenerator).

Comment: To further clarify, the provider token is the value of the `pt` parameter of any campaign link generated with the above linked campaign generator tool.